# Is it possible to get current route name/path inside didChangeAppLifecycleState

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I need to call an API when the app is resumed on a specific page, I have implemented `WidgetsBindingObserver` at the root widget and is observing the whole app state to tigger biometric authentication when the app pauses and resumes.

I need to check if the user is on the home page and if it is I need to call an api from my provider. Is there any way I can achieve this

I tried using `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name` and it always returns null
I also tried adding a separate `WidgetsBindingObserver` on my home screen but triggers every time when any screen is paused and resumed.

main.dart

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      // Check if the user is on the home page and call API
      // if (isUserOnHomePage()) {
      //   callAPI();
      // }
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to achieve this?